# Routing vs Url Rewrite (IIS7) Performance

Tags: .net, asp.net, url-rewriting, url-routing

I was wondering is there any difference in terms of performance between the two approaches? Any good articles on this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lets think about the difference in what's actually happening:

URL rewriting:

- IIS receives request and passes it to unmanaged module
- Module matches the request against a set of patterns and returns a transformation
- IIS passes the returned transformation to the ASP.NET module and starts request lifecycle

Routing:

- IIS receives request and passes it to ASP.NET
- ASP.NET matches the request against a set of patterns and determines an entry point for handling the request
- ASP.NET begins request lifecycle on that handler

I'd say the two are so close you'd be hard-pressed to find a situation where the difference is noticeable.

Comment: The added benefit of Routing is that you get the full power and flexability of .NET at your fingertips, so your routing configuration and code are more familiar and integrated into the rest of your ASP.NET site.

Comment: Routing only affects pages that are handled by .net. For some legacy sites that still use VBScript (.asp), Routing will not work. However the IIS ReWrite Module does still work.